# cakephp simple user registration and authentication (register and login)

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I want to code a cakephp controller for user registration and authentication that would have the register function, login function and log out function.
So far i found examples with user registration http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2008/01/08/simple-user-registration-in-cakephp/
and user authetication , but no complete example , with both : register and login. Does anyone know>?

Comment: Registration = normal form with validation, plenty of examples all over. Authentication = built-in component with plenty of documentation and examples all over. Have you *tried* anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1261/login and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1255/AuthComponent-Methods